# Bottom sheet onTouch() is not called

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I have a simple `CoordinatorLayout` with a `ConstraintLayout` as a bottom sheet and 2 other views. The bottom sheet works fine but I can't seem to get touch events on any of the views.

xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/way_finding_pin_background"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/way_finding_pin_background"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/way_finding_bar_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/way_finding_pin"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_location"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/way_finding_bar_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/way_finding_bar_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="64dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
     app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        >


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity:

```
wayFindingBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTouch() bar called with: v = [" + v + "], event = [" + event + "]");
                wayFindingPin.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });

wayFindingPinBkg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTouch() pin background called with: v = [" + v + "], event = [" + event + "]");
                wayFindingPin.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });

wayFindingPin.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouch() pin called with: view = [" + view + "], event = [" + event + "]");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

None of the onTouch listeners in the activity are being ever called. How can I intercept touch events in such a case?

Comment: did u try for setonclicklistener?

Comment: and what actually want to do with your code?

Comment: No because what I really want to do is drag and drop `way_finding_pin` on touch.

Comment: can just explain more ?

Comment: I have an activity with a bottom sheet. On the bottom sheet there is an image (`way_finding_pin `). I want to be able to drag and drop this image from the bottom sheet into the main layout (`content_main`).

Comment: for that u have to mess with canvas

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why it happen but "android:animateLayoutChanges" = "true" is the reason. I don't enough time to detect why.
You should try it.